# How to find all rownames differing by one character and are of exact length and merge them in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am fairly new to R. I have duplicate rows that differ only by either a "." or a "-", similar to this example.

```
df <- data.frame(cell1 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), cell2 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
rownames(df) <- c("HLA.F", "HLA.G", "HLA.A", "HLA-F", "HLA-G", "HLA-A", "HLA-F-AS1", "HLA-E")

          cell1 cell2
HLA.F         0     0
HLA.G         1     1
HLA.A         2     2
HLA-F         3     3
HLA-G         4     4
HLA-A         5     5
HLA-F-AS1     6     6
HLA-E         7     7
```

I would like to essentially merge the duplicate rows only differing by either a "." or a "-" and replace it with the "." version like this.

```
           cell1 cell2
HLA.F         3     3
HLA.G         5     5
HLA.A         7     7
HLA-F-AS1     6     6
HLA-E         7     7
```

Here is what I have so far. It finds and replaces the duplicates sort of, but I don't know what to do with `HLA-F`/`HLA.F`/`HLA-F-AS1` (I only want the rownames that are the same length, so `HLA-F-AS1` would remain unchanged) or `HLA-E` which has no duplicates.

```
for (i in unique(rownames(df)))
{
  test <- grep(i, unique(rownames(df)))
  df.2 <- t(df[test,])
  #get duplicated names
  df.2.cols <- colnames(df.2)
  #get name with period
  test.period <- grep("[.]",df.2.cols, value = TRUE)
  #merge them
  df.2 <- apply(df.2[,df.2.cols], 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
  df.2 <- t(as.data.frame(df.2))
  rownames(df.2) <- test.period
  #remove duplicates and replace it with merged row
  df <- df[!(row.names(df) %in% df.2.cols), ]
  df <- rbind(df, df.2)
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense and thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert the rownames to a column, then create a grouping column without punctuation, and use that to determine which rownames were duplicated and change `-` to a `.`. Then, we can summarise and put back into rownames.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column('id') %>%
  group_by(grp = str_remove(id, "[[:punct:]]")) %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(n() > 1, str_replace_all(id, '-', '.'), id)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = T))) %>%
  column_to_rownames("id")
```

**Output**

```
          cell1 cell2
HLA-E         7     7
HLA-F-AS1     6     6
HLA.A         7     7
HLA.F         3     3
HLA.G         5     5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! My df has 244014 columns actually heh - is there any way to do this for that many columns?

Comment: @KaitS Do you mean that you need to summarise across all 244014 columns? Or do you have other columns that you will not need to sum? Yes, it is definitely possible to do that rather than just specifying the columns. I've updated my answer so that it would work across all columns.

Comment: I need it to only sum the duplicates, but leave everything else unchanged (so only sum HLA-F/HLA.F but not affect HLA-F-AS1 or HLA-E which had no duplicates). I think this does that right?

Comment: @KaitS Yes, that is what it is doing. I was more asking if you had other columns that had non-numeric data. So, if you only wanted to summarise the numeric columns, then we could replace `everything()` above with `where(is.numeric)`. But it sounds like that is not needed here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

df$n <- gsub("[,-]+" , "." , rownames(df))
chs <- names(which(table(df$n) > 1))
df$rnm <- ifelse(gsub("[,-]+" , "." , rownames(df)) %in% chs ,
       gsub("[,-]+" , "." , rownames(df)) , rownames(df))

df |> group_by(rnm) |> summarise(cell1 = sum(cell1) , cell2 = sum(cell2))

df
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  rnm       cell1 cell2
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 HLA-E         7     7
2 HLA-F-AS1     6     6
3 HLA.A         7     7
4 HLA.F         3     3
5 HLA.G         5     5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! My df has 244014 columns actually heh - is there any way to do this for that many columns?